# Does Dojo have a default CSS file with no theme applied?

Tags: css, dojo, stylesheet

I am trying to build a new design on an old system that is using DOJO, eventually we are going to move to AJAX to handle the data calls. Is there a default or minified CSS file so I don't have to use their themes? (i.e. Claro, which is the theme that was and still is applied)

It says you can make custom themes, but there has to be a bare bones version out there somewhere.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bare minium CSS is available in `dijit.css`
(you can see the file on the CDN: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/dijit.css)

As dojo team says about this file :

> Essential styles that themes can inherit.
>     In other words, works but doesn't look great.

So be aware it will be ugly!
But you can build your own theme starting from that.

Answer (score 2):

dojo comes with out of the box the following themes:

- Claro
- Tundra
- Soria
- Nihilo

There is no really a default CSS a part of the CSS which is included in on of the listed theme. But as ben point out in his answer, there is a `dijit.css` which is a very essential base of CSS which other themes can in-heritage from.

You can apply them adding the following in your HTML file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
<body class="claro">
```

Or you can use a CDN, example for `claro` (just change the name for css file in order to get a different theme):

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css
```

The CDN version is an unique file and easy to include in your app but it is not minified.

If you need to have a minified version, you could use the dojo build to compact all your project files and included CSS for your theme minified.

More info here:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/themes.html#id10

Comment: I was really just looking for that file Ben linked to, but thanks for adding to the information, I'm sure it will help others out!